# AVAudioPlayer playback results in class _NSThreadPerformInfo autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, avaudioplayer

Mucho tiempo wasted on this - I have fairly straightforward playback using AVAudioPLayer but when the file finishes playing I get this message in the debug window:

> objc[39752]: Object 0x7304d80 of class _NSThreadPerformInfo
>   autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking - break on
>   objc_autoreleaseNoPool() to debug

Here are my play and callback functions (I have simplified the filename creation but the error is the same):

```
@implementation PlaybackEngine {
    int _pbIndex;
    AVAudioPlayer *_player;
    NSArray *fileList;
    BufferStores *_BS;
}
....

    -(BOOL)startPlayback {
        NSURL *playURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[[DOCUMENTS_FOLDER stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"28Jan13_17:13:21.aif"] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        printf("Playback file URL = %s\n", [[playURL path] UTF8String]);
        _player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:playURL error:nil];
        _player.delegate = self;

        [_player prepareToPlay];
        [_player play];

        self.playing = YES;
        return YES;    
    }

    -(void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag {

        // check for player stopping due to bad audio data
        if (!flag) {
            printf("Player finished playing due to bad audio data");
        }

        self.playing = NO;
        _player = nil;

    }
```

I've tried setting a breakpoint on `objc_autoreleaseNoPool` but it never gets hit. What blindingly obvious ARC mistake am I making?

Comment: Are you executing this in a background thread? are you sure you have an autorelease pool created in that thread?

Comment: No it's in the main thread. I can't even work out what _NSThreadPerformInfo is, doesn't come up in a search of the documentation nor stackoverflow.

Comment: Did you modify your main.m? You should have an @autoreleasepool { .... } thing there

Comment: Yup I have that, if I didn't there would be a lot more error messages I reckon! Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I seem to have solved it. Apple Dev Support told me that this error should never happen, which made me think it must be some obscure bug in the 5.x SDK, but in the end I tidied up all my classes, redefining ivars as either properties or properties in an extension as appropriate, made sure all my property modifiers were correct etc and the problem has gone.

Sorry I can't explicitly pinpoint the culprit, but clearly a memory management issue.